# Memento patterns doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, design-patterns, memento

I tried to implement some implementation of [Memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) in Java.

Example is easy - copy video game as example, when user press `F5` save gamer state => after pressing `F9` recover last saved gamer state.

Here is output from easy run:

```
Health:          100
Killed Monsters:   0
Health:           90
Killed Monsters:   2
Health:           81
Killed Monsters:   4
Health:           72
Killed Monsters:   6
Health:           64
Killed Monsters:   8
Health:           57
Killed Monsters:  10
```

But it is wrong result, because last 2 lines should be:

```
Health:           90
Killed Monsters:   2
```

I couldn't figure out what is wrong. Code looks ok.

Here is code snippet:

```
import java.util.Stack;

class GameState {
    private int health;
    private int killedMonsters;

    public GameState(int health, int killedMonsters) {
        this.health = health;
        this.killedMonsters = killedMonsters;
    }

    public double getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public int getKilledMonsters() {
        return killedMonsters;
    }

    public void setHealth(int health) {
        this.health = health;
    }

    public void setKilledMonsters(int killedMonsters) {
        this.killedMonsters = killedMonsters;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  String.format("Health: %1$12d\nKilled Monsters: %2$3d", health, killedMonsters);
    }
}

class GameMemento {
    private GameState gameState;

    public GameMemento(GameState gameState) {
        this.gameState = gameState;
    }

    public GameState getGameState() {
        return gameState;
    }
}

class GameOriginator {
    private GameState gameState = new GameState(100, 0);

    public void play() {
        System.out.println(gameState.toString());
        gameState.setHealth((int)(gameState.getHealth() * 0.9));
        gameState.setKilledMonsters(gameState.getKilledMonsters() + 2);
    }

    public GameMemento saveGame() {
        return new GameMemento(gameState);
    }

    public void loadGame(GameMemento memento) {
        gameState = memento.getGameState();
    }
}

class Caretacker {
    private GameOriginator game = new GameOriginator();
    private Stack<GameMemento> quickSaves = new Stack<>();

    public void shutThisDumbAss() {
        game.play();
    }

    public void F5() {
        quickSaves.push(game.saveGame());
    }

    public void F9() {
        game.loadGame(quickSaves.peek());
    }
}

public class MementoDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Caretacker caretacker = new Caretacker();
        caretacker.F5();
        caretacker.shutThisDumbAss();
        caretacker.F5();
        caretacker.shutThisDumbAss();
        caretacker.shutThisDumbAss();
        caretacker.shutThisDumbAss();
        caretacker.shutThisDumbAss();
        caretacker.F9();
        caretacker.shutThisDumbAss();
    }
}
```

***Any suggestions?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are reusing the same `GameState` reference in the `GameMemento` object. So when you change **property** of the `GameState` object, it is also changing the one that were saved in the `GameMemento`.

To fix this is necessary to save a copy of the `GameState` object instead its original reference, change your code as the example below:

```
public GameMemento saveGame() {
     return new GameMemento(new GameState(gameState.getHealth(), gameState.getKilledMonsters()));
}
```

You can also use the [clone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) method to copy the current instance of the `GameState`.

Answer (score 1):

Your stack is having the reference to same GameOriginator object. You save the defensive copy in stack for retreiving it later.

```
public GameMemento saveGame() {
 return new GameMemento(new GameState(gameState.getHealth(), gameState.getKilledMonsters()));
}
```